# A word for something you give and the receiver knows you will come back to get it?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, money

What’s the word for something you give someone to ensure that you will come back to get it? For example, if you get a loan, you have to list your valuable assets so they can take those if you don’t pay them back.

Comment: There could be different terms depending on if the person actually leaves the valuable item behind to retrieve later (a deposit) or if they merely agree to give up the item if they don't pay, but never actually give up the item so long as they do pay (collateral).

Answer (score 7):

**Collateral**

(n) property (such as securities) pledged by a borrower to protect the interests of the lender

Answer (score 1):

A security deposit.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/security-deposit.asp

A security deposit for renting an apartment is returned if the apartment is in good condition when you vacate it.

A security deposit for renting a bike or a boat ensures that you’ll return the rented item to get the deposit back. Sometimes a credit card is used with the agreement that the card will be charged if you don’t return the item.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Xanne's answer, sometimes it is simply called **"security"**:

> Do not take a pair of millstones or even an upper millstone as security for a debt, because that would be taking one's livelihood as security. ([Bible, Deuteronomy, laws of social responsibility, CSB](https://biblehub.com/csb/deuteronomy/24.htm))

Or **"a pledge"**:

> If you ever take your neighbor's cloak as a pledge, you are to return it to him before the sun sets... ([Bible, Exodus, laws of social responsibility, NASB 1995](https://biblehub.com/nasb/exodus/22.htm))